# Overload input stream operator>> for reading objects from file

Tags: c++, file-io, operator-overloading, istream

I have a simple class `City`, which contains `id`, `name`, `sizeOfPopulation` and coordinates `x` and `y`. I have a text file, which looks like this:

```
City;1;Stockholm;300000;45;78;
City;2;Helsinky;451200;11;74;
City;3;Prague;897455;12;85;
```

Each line means following: The first in an indicator, that it is a city. Next is ID of city, name, size of population, x and y.

I want to read this file and creates a vector with cities. I know, that I need to overload an operator <<.

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, City& c)
{
    // I do not know
}
```

After that, I would be able to loads cities from a file in `for` loop. Can you help me please with overloading operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>

friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, City& c)
{
    // get whole line
    string line;
    if (!getline(is, line))
    {
        // error reporting and exit goes here...
    }

    // replace all ';' to ' '
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        if (line[i] == ';')
            line[i] = ' ';
    }

    // start parsing here
    istringstream iss(line);
    string tmp;
    if (iss >> tmp >> c.id >> c.name >> sizeOfPopulation >> c.x >> c.y)
    {
        // error reporting and exit goes here...
    }

    return input;
}
```

---

To read `City` objects in a loop, you can use:

```
City c;
while (is >> c) // suppose "is" is the opened input stream
{
    // successfully read a City, stored in c
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the `input`, which you returned?

Comment: @PSglass Fixed. Typo here. :P

Comment: Thank you. It seems that it works. But now I do not know how can I read cities in loop. I have `while (getline(inputFile, line))` but I do not know the body of loop. Please, can you give me an advice?

Comment: Have you actually tested this code?  With e.g. "Hong Kong".  This is _not_ the best way to do it (and as you've implemented it, it isn't even correct).

Comment: @JamesKanze Added error checking part. Could you share some ideas on the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest you test it with a legal line for the city of "Hong Kong".  It will fail when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd use `getline` to read the line, then break it
up on the `';'`, using something like:

```
std::vector<std::string>
split( std::string const& source, char separ )
{
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    std::string::const_iterator start = source.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = source.end();
    std::string::const_iterator next = std::find( start, end, separ );
    while ( next != end ) {
        results.push_back( std::string( start, next ) );
        start = next + 1;
        next = std::find( start, end, separ );
    }
    results.push_back( std::string( start, end ) );
}
```

(You may want to extend this to trim leading and trailing
spaces, etc.)

For the fields which are strings, you can just index into the
`std::vector`; for the others, use the string value to
initialize an `std::istringstream` to convert them (or
`std::stoi`, if you have C++11).  So you'd end up with something
like:

```
std::istream&
operator>>( std::istream& source, City& dest )
{
    std::string record;
    if ( std::getline( source, record ) ) {
        std::vector<std::string> fields = split( record );
        if ( fields.size() != 7 || fields[0] != "City" || fields[6] != "" ) {
            source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
        } else {
            try {
                dest = City( std::stoi( vector[1] ),
                             std::vector[2],
                             std::stoi( vector[3] ),
                             Coordinates( std::stoi( vector[4] ),
                                          std::stoi( vector[5]) ) ) );
            catch ( ... ) {
                source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
            }
        }
    }
    return source;
}
```

(The need for the `try ... catch` isn't very nice, but that's
the way `std::stoi` reports its errors.)